# Stats and Probability: Three cups and Two different integers in each. Combinations?

Tags: probability, statistics

Can’t explain much in the title. 
To set the stage:
There are three cups (#1, #2, and #3).  In each cup is two cards with different integers. There are 6 different integers that run 1-6. In cup #1 is 1 and 2, in cup #2 is 3 and 4, and so forwardth. The cups are randomized and you have to pull one card from each cup, and then one last card from the last cup you most recently pulled from. What is the probability that one particular string of values would come out? 
So:

> Pull from “cup #2”: 3
>   Pull from “cup #1”: 2
>   Pull from “cup #3”: 6
>   Make a second draw from “cup #3”: Has to be 5
>   String is: 3,2,6,5.

-Order matters
-Keep in mind that the cards are replaced after all cards have been pulled. 
My example is complicated to me so please ask away for any clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the string is valid (i.e., respects the above rules), the probability equals:

$$\frac{1}{{6 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1}} = \frac{1}{6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2} = \frac{1}{48}$$

This is because you can choose among 6 numbers for the first digit, among 4 numbers for the second, and finally the order of the 2 remaining numbers.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me through the the answer!

Comment: @UnhealthyIndividualist You're welcome. If this or any other answer was of help to you, please don't forget to accept it by ticking the check mark on the left!

Answer (score 0):

Approach via multiplication principle and counting.

- Choose the order of the cups: $3!$ options
- Pick a card from the left-most cup: $2$ options
- Pick a card from the middle cup: $2$ options
- Pick a card from the right-most cup: $2$ options
- Pick the remaining card from the right-most cup: $1$ option

Multiplying the number of options gives the number of possible outcomes being $48$.  Assuming each outcome is equally likely, the probability of getting a particular possible outcome is simply $1$ divided by the number of outcomes, i.e. $\frac{1}{48}$.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about factorials, at least I think that is what this is “!”

Comment: @UnhealthyIndividualist factorials can also be explained via multiplication principle.  To choose the order of the cups, first pick which cup is on the left (3 options), then pick which cup is in the middle (2 options), and the remaining cup goes on the right, for a total of $3\cdot 2=6$ options total.